# Vagrant: How to mount Linux shared folder in Windows

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Host System: Ubuntu Linux, Guest system: Windows (any version).

I want to share a Linux folder on a Windows system.

When I use VirtualBox, I configure all the settings through the GUI. The Shared Folders settings look like this:

```
Name: downloads
Path: /home/user/downloads
Access: Full
Auto Mount: Yes
At: Z:
```

After starting the virtual machine, the shared folder appears to be mounted to disk `Z`, all is well.

Question: how can I do the same with Vagrant?

I created an image of the virtual machine in the `package.box` file. Then I configured Vagrant (`config.vm.box = "./package.box"`), and started the machine. All good, but how can I configure Shared Folders to mount automatically?

I have tried different options, my last option:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../shared-data", "X:\\", create: true, id: "X"
```

The Shared Folders settings look like this:

```
Name: X
Path: /home/user/downloads
Access: Full
Auto Mount: (empty)
At: (empty)
```

How can I get Vagrant to automatically mount shared folders (`Auto Mount`, `At`)?

Just in case: the guest system does not have SSH configured, so Vagrant hangs on the message "Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes". I'll fix that later, the VM starts and works correctly.

PS. Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "./package.box"

  config.vm.synced_folder "../shared-data", "X:\\", create: true, id: "X"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name = "Win Vagrant test"
    vb.gui = true

    vb.memory = "2048"
    vb.cpus = 2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the provider.
With virtualbox; define the shares as you would for linux guests.
`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: false`
and virtualbox will mount it under `C:\vagrant` which appears to be a link to `\\vboxsvr\vagrant\` but that notation won't work in the vagrant config.

Additional folders will show up the same way. Not sure what happens if the folder name is protected, longer than 8 chars or uses banned characters on windows. Those are good limits to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try a little later. I'm experimenting on Windows XP (I'm just comfortable doing it that way). End goal: I want to do it on Windows 10. Is there any difference?

Comment: Not sure. I was using a windows server 2022 guest. gusztavvargadr/windows-server

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that Vagrant mounts the shared directories **after** the virtual machine boots. But in my case, Vagrant waited for the VM to boot for a few minutes, but did not detect that it was booted, and then showed an error. Vagrant checks for VM availability via SSH or WinRM.

Here is what I did:

1. Started and configured WinRM: `winrm quickconfig`
2. Configured the WinRM service to start automatically (it was a delayed start) - this I speeds up detection, but not necessary
3. Created user `vagrant` and included it in the Administrators group to be able to work with WinRM.
4. Fixed the Vagrant config:

```
  # WinRM
  config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
  config.winrm.username = "vagrant"
  config.winrm.password = "vagrant"
  config.winrm.max_tries = 300 # default is 20
  config.winrm.retry_delay = 2 #seconds. This is the defaul value and just here for documentation.

  # Shared folder  
  config.vm.synced_folder "../shared-data", "/vagrant"
```

Here is a portion of the boot log that shows that directory mounts only occur after the VM boot event is received.

```
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 5985 (guest) => 55985 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5986 (guest) => 55986 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: WinRM address: 127.0.0.1:55985
    default: WinRM username: vagrant
    default: WinRM execution_time_limit: PT2H
    default: WinRM transport: negotiate
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
[default] GuestAdditions 6.1.48 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/user/tmp/vagrant-test/shared-data
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```